# Problem with rendering React component with input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that looks like that:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Form = ({ state, setNameValue }) => {
  const [nameValue, setCurrentNameValue] = useState(state.message.name.value);

  const nameChange = (e) => {
    console.log(state.message.name.value);
    setNameValue(e.target.value);
    console.log(state.message.name.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentNameValue(state.message.name.value);
  }, [state.message.name.value]);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      placeholder={state.message.name.placeholder}
      value={nameValue}
      onChange={(e) => nameChange(e)}
    />
  );
};
```

And I want it to update state value, then get this value and rerender, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't `setNameValue` be `setCurrentNameValue` inside the `nameChange` handler?

Comment: Maybe your code is different, but you're also not importing `useState` or `useEffect` in your example.

Comment: `useState` and `useEffect` are imported, sorry, I'll edit question. `nameChange` is supposed to edit value in `state`. `setCurrentNameValue` is used to edit `useState` according to the value from `state` file.

Comment: You still have `setNameValue` which doesn't exist in your component. Your current code actually works to update the state locally if you change it. You're just printing the value of the prop not the internal state.

Comment: The useEffect callback is basically useless because the component will rerender/recompute the state when it changes. You can't mutate props and have parent state change with React. Look into the Context API or a state management tool.